# quiero variables independientes

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una variable que es un object con 2 nodos:

```
var jDef = {id: 'hola', valores: [{cod: 1, desc: 'dddd'}, {cod: 2, desc: 'bbbb'}]}
```

en otro punto del programa, hago:

```
var jTemp.valores[1] = $.extend(jDef.valores[1], {selected: true});
```

Esto funciona como espero.

Si en su lugar lo tengo así (función que recoge la lista de una BBDD):

```
var jDef = {id: 'hola', valores: obtenerListaBBDD()};
var jTemp = $.extend({ },  jDef);
jTemp.valores[1] = $.extend(jDef.valores[1], {selected: true});
```

El nodo nuevo 'selected' aparece en ambas variables (jDef y jTemp), cuando yo quiero que sólo se incluya en jTemp.

Alguien me puede aclarar los conceptos o dar una solución?

He montado un jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u44eg64y/17/

Saludos,

SeakOink
(he editado pregunta, ya que no era exacta)

EDIT:

Este es el código real. jCRUD.Datatable[n].valors_admesos[1] tiene el mismo valor que jTemp.valors_admesos[1] (con el nuevo nodo "selected":

```
        var jTemp = $.extend({}, jCRUD.DataTable[n], {data: sValor}); //Subtitueix el node "data" amb el valor calculat
        nn = 0;
        nnTotal = _.size(jTemp.valors_admesos);
        while (nn < nnTotal) {
            // Bucle en cas de tenir una llista de valors en un <select>, el qual marcarà com a "selected" el <option> que correspon al valor
            if (jTemp.valors_admesos[nn].valor === sValor) {
                jTemp.valors_admesos[nn] = $.extend({}, jTemp.valors_admesos[nn], {selected: 'selected'}); // Marco el valor del camp com a seleccionat a dins la llista
            }
            nn++;
        }
```

Comment: Mira el último parrafo de mi respuesta. ¡ y no te olvides de puntuar ? ;-)

Comment: Dices que, después de ejecutar el `$.extend( )`, `data:sValor` aparece también dentro de `jCRUD.DataTable[n]`, además de en `jTemp` ?

Comment: Porque eso no puede ser. ¿ seguro que `data` no está ya en `jCRUD.DataTable[n]` ?

Comment: si, data ya está en `jCRUD.DataTable[n] has mirado el ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/u44eg64y/17/ ?

Comment: Ok. Respuesta actualizada con tu nuevos fuentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> De la documentación de jQuery:
>
> [`$.extend( target, obj1, \[ obj2 \] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)
>   Añade el contenido de los obj1, obj2, al **target**, y devuelve este último.

Es decir, que el comportamiento correcto y esperado es el que tú das por erróneo. Lo raro es el primer caso, que según dices, no hace lo mismo... ¿Seguro que en el primer caso que expones, *ambos*, `jTemp` y `jDef`, no terminan con los mismos atributos?

- Si lo que quieres es añadir un *atributo* a un objeto ya creado, es tan fácil como hacer una simple asignación.
- Si lo que quieres es obtener un objeto que mezcle otros 2, sería:

  ```js
  result = $.extend( { }, obj1, obj2 }
  ```

---

#### Descripción

`$.extend( )` *extiende* el objeto pasado como primer argumento con los atributos de los otros objetos, y devuelve ese primer argumento. Como le pasamos un objeto vacío, sin contenido previo, **copia** el contenido de los otros 2 objetos sobre ese *objeto vacio*; al finalizar, **target** contiene todos los atributos contenidos en los otros 2, que no han sido modificados.

Por último, `$.extend( )` nos devuelve el objeto que le pasamos como primer argumento (recordemos que los objetos se pasan por *referencia*), con lo que ya tenemos nuestra *operacion* **union** realizada.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function obtenerBBDD() {
    return [{cod: 1, desc: '111'}, {cod: 2, desc: '222'}];
}

var jDef = {id: 'hola', valores: obtenerBBDD()};
// jDef = {"id":"hola","valores":[{"cod":1,"desc":"111"},{"cod":2,"desc":"222"}]}

var jTemp = $.extend({ },  jDef);
// jTemp = {"id":"hola","valores":[{"cod":1,"desc":"111"},{"cod":2,"desc":"222","selected":true}]}
```

Aqui empezamos con los problemas. `jTemp["valores"]` no es un objeto independiente, es una **referencia** al `"valores"` contenido en `jDef`.

Es decir, `jTemp.valores` **es el mismo objeto** que `jDef.valores`. Por lo tanto, cualquier cambio a uno de ellos afecta al otro.

**Posibles soluciones**

1. Usar `$.extend( )` con un argumento **true** inicial, para que haga una copia *recursiva*:

   ```js
   var jTemp = $.extend( true, { }, jDef )
   ```

   Según la documentación, ese `true` inicial forzará la copia *recursiva*, de modo que `jTemp` y `jDef` no estén enlazados, y se resuelva el problema.
2. Usar otra librería, que sí realice un **deep copy**, si jQuery no lo permite.

Comment: he editado mi pregunta, pues no era exactamente mi caso. A ver si ahora está mejor. Me interesa que jTemp.valores no esté vinculado con jDef.valores (me lo cambia).

Comment: Vale, entiendo que devuelve el mismo objeto que el original (con los cambios y por referencia).

Comment: De que forma puedo conseguir un nuevo objeto? Con el contenido de jDef?

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices ahora. Lo de un nuevo objeto, ya te lo he explicado. Pasa 3 argumentos a `extend`: un **objeto vacio**, y otros 2, que te los mezclará en el primero, **que estaba vacio**.

Comment: Lo pruebo en un rato (estoy en la calle) , pero diria que ya lo habia hecho

Comment: Lo acabo de probar con el primer argumento {} y se comporta igual

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon el código exacto, por favor. El que has utilizado ahora, con 3 argumentos, el primero `{ }`.

Comment: editado con el código real

Comment: He montado un jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u44eg64y/17/ para ilustrar el caso

Comment: Has dado en el clavo! Wow! Gracias mil